# Delphi XE2: Encounter "Error Reading Form" when opening a project in IDE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I attempt to upgrade a project group containing 200 projects from Delphi XE to Delphi XE2.  Some of the IDE design components aren't install on Delphi XE2 IDE yet.

I encounter error when open some projects in Delphi XE2 IDE:

```
"Error Reading Form: Class TSynEdit not found. Ignore the error and continue?
Note: Ignoring the error may cause components to be deleted or property values
to be lost".
```

This is due to TSynEdit component is not install in the Delphi XE2 IDE.

I am in the stage of upgrading to estimate how much works I need to do. As I didn't open the form containing missing component, these messages keep prompt out whenever I open the project. It is very irritating.

Prior to Delphi XE2's IDE, these messages prompt out only when I open the form in IDE. It doesn't happen when I open project file in IDE. However, in Delphi XE2, these messages prompt out when I open project file IDE.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You obviously know what the problem is (you need to install TSynEdit). I don't see anything that needs an answer here.

Comment: I don't have TSynEdit for Delphi XE2 yet.  I may ignore that at the moment, but the message keep prompt out whenever I open the project group.  The message doesn't prompt out in Delphi XE IDE.  Is there any option to disable the message?

Comment: Whe you save the project, are you saving the desktop? If so, the forms open when the project was saved will open when the project is opened the next time. (I use this to automatically open the forms I've worked on last.) This could be the cause of getting the prompts. You might try renaming the .dsk files for the projects before trying to open them.

Comment: I try to adjust the contains clause of .dpk file and the problem gone.  If the first UI form contain unregistered design component in contain clause, the message will prompt out.  I move away the form and promote other form in .dpk file that have all valid registered components, then open .dpk file will be fine in IDE.

Comment: I found the solution, just save the project file in Delphi XE2 and the problem will not happen again next time.  The Delphi XE2 .dproj file should have new stuffs that avoid the error message happen.

Comment: XE2 internally opens all forms while upgrading the project. If you don't save the project it will be upgraded again the next time you open it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As David suggested, now my comment as an answer.

XE2 internally opens all forms while upgrading the project. If you don't save the project it will be upgraded again the next time you open it.

So as you found by yourself: Save the project file, but don't save the forms as this would destroy the references to the non-existing components.